# Sharepoint and React: Web Part Table Grid Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sharepoint-online

I've been researching Data Tables and Grids in React and I would like to use one or two but my data is not rendering into the Grid. Local data from Json is working fine and the current one I am trying to use is Allen's React Bootstrap Table http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#custom but it's just my list from a Sharepoint Online List that's not rendering even though it's being returned and can be confirmed via alerts or in HTTP Response. My code is below, please advise where I am missing something and I believe it's to do with how I Render my Columns as there's a few ways of doing thus causing confusion.

```
//Render
public render(): React.ReactElement<IAZProps> {

  var nameArray = [];
  var dataArray = [];
  var fitems = [];
  var ritems = [];
  var tableColumn: any;

  this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/sites/dev-site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CourseBookingTest')/items`,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'odata-version': ''
      }
    })
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
      //alert(`Successfully loaded ` + response.json() + ` items`);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }) => {

        alert(`Successfully loaded ` + response.value.length + ` items`);

        fitems = response.value

        for(var i=0;i<fitems.length;i++){
          dataArray.push(fitems[i]);
          console.log(fitems[i]); 
       }

       nameArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
         //alert(item.Id); 

               return {
               value: item.Location, 
               title: item.Location, 
               id: item.Id,
               location: item.Location
                  };
        });

    }, (error: any): void => {

        alert('Loading all items failed with error' + error);

    });

return (
      <div className="container">
          <div>
               <h6>Location Search</h6>
               <div>  
              <BootstrapTable
                      data={ritems}
                      selectRow={selectRowProp}
                      striped
                      hover
                      condensed
                      pagination
                      insertRow
                      deleteRow
                      search>
                  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey dataAlign="right" dataSort>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="location" dataAlign="center" >Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>


              </div>
          </div>
          Component 2
          <PanelB count={10} 
          key={null} onChange=""
          index={null} id={null} onRemove details="" description={this.props.description} text="" title="" category={this.props.category} image={this.props.image}> 
           Hello World I am component 2
           </PanelB>
          <div>


          </div>
      </div>  

    );//Return
  }//Response
}//Class
```

EDIT:
[Data not rendering from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZSin.png)
[Data rendering from local json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmwmf.png)

Comment: Post the HTML output additionally to that code and specify your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Yes sure. I've screenshot'd the results in edit above.

Comment: You might want to re-read my comment one more time...

Comment: What do you mean by 'Post' the HTML output? Do you want to see rendered HTML from browser? Regarding the version I don't know how much it's matter although it'll be hidden in the React Bootstrap Table module files (js, etc) , it does appear that this module is not using Bootstrap from cdn. Looks like he copied the Bootstrap and then did work to make output as a node module.

Comment: If you want to argue with me instead of posting the required info and data here, then you can as well just answer your own question...

Comment: Thanks @WebDevBooster but I did believe the answer has nothing to do with the Bootstrap version. If it was a non server based app maybe so but since it was a server side (server-less!!) side formatting issue I knew it was the Bootstrap. Please see my answer below for future ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here is the answer for those who need it as it may help. To note are a few things below. Thanks to those who tried to help. A fetch() version is also added. Please note both solutions need a holder model/Array as shown below.

1. **Data source was wrong**

   `data={productsGlobal}` - this is the datasource that should have been passed in to the data field whereas I was passing in `data={ritems}`.
2. **Loop through filtered items**

I was wasn't looping through the filtered items...instead I was just formatting them. I needed an extra for loop:

```
  //push to a more usable array
    //Use this for final data source for he table
     for(var i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
       productsGlobal.push(nameArray[i]);
       //alert('I am ritems of item ' + nameArray[1].id);

       }
```

**3. Finally it turns out that the MUI UI elements now need to be wrapped in the  Mui Theme Provider like so:**

```
   `<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}> </BootstrapTable><AutoComplete/></MuiThemeProvider>`
```

**and properly importing and instantiating looks like so:**

```
     `import Autocomplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
// since the export is a function, this is the only actual correct way:
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({});`
```

**Final result should look like so:**

```
export default class AZ extends React.Component<IAZProps, INpmsharepoint2State> {

//Holder array
    var productsGlobal = [{
    id: '',
    title: '',
    location: ''}];


//Initialise data in CompDidMount is the best place
//according to best practices
componentDidMount() {
  var nameArray = [];
  var dataArray = [];
  var fitems = [];
  var ritems = [];
 // var products = [];
  var tableColumn: any;

this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/sites/dev-`sm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CourseBookingTest')/items`,
SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
 {
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
     'odata-version': ''
   }
 })
 .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
   //alert(`Successfully loaded ` + response.json() + ` items`);
   return response.json();
 })
 .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }) => {

     alert(`Successfully loaded ` + response.value.length + ` items`);

     //1 Response value to fitmes
     fitems = response.value

     //1 for each of response item push to data array
     //2 still json object so not string
      for(var i=0;i<fitems.length;i++){
        dataArray.push(fitems[i]);
        console.log(fitems[i]); 
     }
    //map the json object to another array and
    //via each object key so it's stringable
    //and can be sent to browser
    nameArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
      //alert(item.Id); 
         //alert(data2[0].title);
            return {
            value: item.Title, 
            title: item.Title, 
            id: item.Id,
            location: item.Location
               };
     });
     //push to a more usable array 
     for(var i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
       productsGlobal.push(nameArray[i]);
       //alert('I am ritems of item ' + nameArray[1].id);

    }
     alert('I am productsglobal of item ' + productsGlobal[1].title);
 }, (error: any): void => {

     alert('Loading all items failed with error' + error);

 });
}//Comp did mount

    //Render
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IAZProps> {

      const { isLoading } = this.state;

      if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading ...</p>;
      }


      const actions = [
        <FlatButton
          label="Cancel"
          primary={true}
          onClick={this.handleClose}
        />,
        <FlatButton
          label="Submit"
          primary={true}
          onClick={this.handleClose}
        />,
      ];

      var MuiAuto = [{title: ''}];
      for(var i=0;i<productsGlobal.length;i++){
        MuiAuto.push(productsGlobal[i]);
        //alert('I am ritems of item ' + nameArray[1].id);
        }


        var selectRowProp = {
          mode: "checkbox",
          clickToSelect: true,
          bgColor: "rgb(238, 193, 213)" 
        };


        // The gray background
        const backdropStyle = {
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
          padding: 50
        };

        // The modal "window"
        const modalStyle = {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          borderRadius: 5,
          maxWidth: 500,
          minHeight: 300,
          margin: '0 auto',
          padding: 30
        };

        const customContentStyle = {
          width: '100%',
          maxWidth: 'none',
        };


        return (


    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <div className="container">
              <div>



                     <RaisedButton backgroundColor="#890458" label="View the A-Z Vic List" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
                <Dialog
                  title="A-Z Vic List"
                  actions={actions}
                  modal={true}
                  contentStyle={customContentStyle}
                  open={this.state.open}>
                  T
                  <div className={styles.azdirectory}  name="azdirectory" id="azdirectory"><br />
                      <BootstrapTable
                              data={productsGlobal}
                              selectRow={selectRowProp}
                              striped
                              hover
                              condensed
                              pagination
                              insertRow
                              deleteRow
                              search>
                          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} dataAlign="right" dataSort width="5%">Course ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort width="25%">Title</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="location" dataAlign="center" width="25%">Location</TableHeaderColumn>
                          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="location" dataAlign="center" width="25%">Dummy</TableHeaderColumn>
                        </BootstrapTable>
                      </div>
                 </Dialog>

              <br /><br /><br />
   <p>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
       <div href='https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki' >
                Learn more
                  </div>
                  <input  id="btnShowSecondComp" type="submit" value="View Locations Directory"/>


                     </div>
                  </div>
        </div>  

        </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
      }//end of Render
 }//end of class
```

Fetch version:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var nameArray = [];
  var dataArray = [];
  var fitems = [];
  var ritems = [];
 // var products = [];
  var tableColumn: any;

 // this.setState({ isLoading: true, myAPIList: [], dataSource: [] });


  //URLs
  var CourseBooking = `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/dev-sm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CourseBookingTest')/items`;
  var AZList = `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/dev-sm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Locations')/items`;

  fetch(CourseBooking, { credentials: "include", headers: { accept: "application/json" } })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }) => {

          //1 Response value to fitems
          fitems = response.value;
          alert('I am fitems plus data ' + fitems + response);
          //1 for each of response item push to data array
          //2 still json object so not string
          //so not browser/ui ready
           for(var i=0;i<fitems.length;i++){
             dataArray.push(fitems[i]);
             console.log(fitems[i]); 
          }
         // alert('I am dataArray' + dataArray);

          if(fetch(CourseBooking)){
            //map the json object to another array
         //via each object key so it's stringable
         //and can be sent to browser
         //as astring if need be too if you request the formatted item
         nameArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
           //alert(item.Id); 
              //alert(data2[0].title);
                 return {
                 value: item.Title, 
                 title: item.Title, 
                 id: item.Id,
                 location: item.Location
                    };   
              });
          } else {

            nameArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
              //alert(item.Id); 
                 //alert(data2[0].title);
                    return {
                    value: item.Title, 
                    title: item.Title, 
                    id: item.Id,
                    location: item.Location
                   ,Office_x0020_Type: item.Office_x0020_Type
                     };   
                 });

          }
         // alert('I am nameArray' + nameArray);
          //push to a more usable array 
          for(var i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
          productsGlobal.push(nameArray[i]);
          //alert('I am ritems of item ' + nameArray[1].id);
          }
         // alert('I am productsglobal of item ' + productsGlobal[1].title);
          //finally set our data object state
          this.setState({myAPIList: response.value, isLoading: false, dataSource: response.value, open: false })
          //this.setState({dataSource: [value,value + value, value + value + value,]})
})//fetch
```